# Wordpress sidebar and footer not showing up

Tags: php, wordpress

Home: http://blog.priworks.com/ Posts: http://bit.ly/19kLqEI Category: http://bit.ly/16rFJUK

I had a pharma hack and installed a clean version of wordpress and copied over only what I needed after cleaning it. I did'nt modify the theme but for some reason the *get* statement isn't working on the categories and posts pages.

```
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Has anyone experienced this, is it safe to try *include* instead?

Posts/Category template single.php

```
<?php
/**
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Default_Theme
 */

get_header();
?>

    <div id="content" class="widecolumn" role="main">

    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <!--<div class="navigation">
            <div class="alignleft"><?php previous_post_link('&laquo; %link') ?></div>
            <div class="alignright"><?php next_post_link('%link &raquo;') ?></div>
        </div>-->

        <div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
            <h6 class="singletitleh6"><?php the_title(); ?></h6>
            <span style="text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 0.8em; letter-spacing: 1px; margin-bottom: 20px; display: block; color: #666;">by <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></span>

            <div class="entry">
                <?php the_content('<p class="serif">Read the rest of this entry &raquo;</p>'); ?>

                <?php wp_link_pages(array('before' => '<p><strong>Pages:</strong> ', 'after' => '</p>', 'next_or_number' => 'number')); ?>

                <p class="postmetadata">
                    <span style="font-size: 0.9em; margin-bottom: 10px; display: block; color: #666;">Posted by <?php the_author_posts_link();?><?php //the_author(); ?> | <a style="color: #666;" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Permalink</a> | <span class="num_comments_style"><?php comments_popup_link(__('Comments (0)'), __('Comments (1)'), __('Comments (%)')); ?></span> | <span style="font-weight: bold;">Trackbacks (<?php  trackback_count(); ?>)</span> | <?php sharethis_button(); ?></span>
                </p>
                <p class="postmetadata"><span style="font-size: 0.9em; margin-bottom: 20px; display: block; color: #666;"><?php the_tags( 'Tags: ', ', ', ''); ?></span></p>
                <p class="postmetadata alt">
                    <small>
                        This entry was posted

                        on <?php the_time('l, F jS, Y') ?> at <?php the_time() ?>
                        and is filed under <?php the_category(', ') ?>.
                        You can follow any responses to this entry through the <?php post_comments_feed_link('RSS 2.0'); ?> feed.

                        <?php if ( comments_open() && pings_open() ) {
                            // Both Comments and Pings are open ?>
                            You can <a href="#respond">leave a response</a>, or <a href="<?php trackback_url(); ?>" rel="trackback">trackback</a> from your own site.

                        <?php } elseif ( !comments_open() && pings_open() ) {
                            // Only Pings are Open ?>
                            Responses are currently closed, but you can <a href="<?php trackback_url(); ?> " rel="trackback">trackback</a> from your own site.

                        <?php } elseif ( comments_open() && !pings_open() ) {
                            // Comments are open, Pings are not ?>
                            You can skip to the end and leave a response. Pinging is currently not allowed.

                        <?php } elseif ( !comments_open() && !pings_open() ) {
                            // Neither Comments, nor Pings are open ?>
                            Both comments and pings are currently closed.

                        <?php } edit_post_link('Edit this entry','','.'); ?>

                    </small>
                </p>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div style="margin: 50px 70px 10px 42px; text-align: left;">
            <?php comments_template(); ?>
        </div>

    <?php endwhile; else: ?>

        <div style="margin: 50px 70px 10px 42px; text-align: left;">
            <p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>
        </div>

<?php endif; ?>

    </div>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: This could be related to some fatal error preventing the rest of the page from rendering. Try to enable [WP Debug](http://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG) to see the exact error.

Comment: Thanks, did that and cleared all issues. There were a few deprecated functions being used and that added support for but still no sidebars. I am updating the question with the code in single.php which should be the template used for posts.